# Bash, &&-ed command list output redirect to stdout

Tags: bash, list, shell, command

My main Bash source of knowledge is `info Bash`. Neither its `Redirections` nor `Commands` > `Lists` section elaborate how redirecting command output is handled by command list. In case here it is &&-ed list of commands: `command1 && command2 && command3`.
What is needed is the output of all 3 commands to be redirected to file.
For Bash used here neither of following works (only command3 output can be find in file redirection to is being made)

```
command1 && command2 && command3 > mycommandoutput.txt

(command1 && command2 && command3) > mycommandoutput.txt

command1 > mycommandoutput.txt && command2 > mycommandoutput.txt && command3 > mycommandoutput.txt

command1 | tee mycommandoutput.txt && command2 | tee mycommandoutput.txt && command3 | tee mycommandoutput.txt

command1 && command2 && command3 | tee mycommandoutput.txt
```

Few further was tried out too, no help.

Where is this Bash aspect specified?

Why do my command strings don't produce described result?

How to fix it?

Comment: `(command1 && command2 && command3) > mycommandoutput.txt` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for hint. It seems to be my own mistake in syntax: each brace character needs to be isolated from remaining tokes by whitespace - according to again `info Bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to redirect multiple commands is with a group `{ ...; }`. Note the `;` at the end, it is important.

```
{ cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3; } > file
```

However, you said you already tried `(cmd1 && cmd1 && cmd3) > file` which should work too. Maybe some of your commands print to stderr instead of stdout. In that case use `{ ...; } &> file` to write both stderr and stdout to the file.

#### Why did the other commands not work?

Apart from the stdout/stderr problem, here are explanations of why the other commands did not work for you:

- `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 > file` redirect only `cmd3`.
- `cmd1 > file && cmd2 > file && cmd3 > file` overwrites `file` twice. The output of `cmd1` is lost because `cmd2` overwrites it. The output of `cmd2` is lost because `cmd3` overwrites it. Instead of overwriting, append to the file using `cmd1 > file && cmd2 >> file && cmd3 >> file`.
- `cmd1 | tee file && cmd2 | tee file && cmd3 | tee file` same as above; `tee` overwrites the file. Use `tee -a` to append instead.

Comment: `cmd1 > file && cmd2 >> file && cmd3 >> file` ` Use tee -a to append instead.`- me to blame, such a basic forgotten.